# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule working on Apache, not on IIS

Tags: wordpress, apache, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am having the following rewrite rule :

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('formation(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?','index.php?pagename=formation&formation_slug=$matches[2]&formation_id=$matches[4]','top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%formation_slug%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%formation_id%','([^&]+)');
}
```

This works fine on my Apache server, and not on my client's IIS.
I flushed the rewrite rules and the Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer plugin tells me the redirection should work as planned.

Any suggestion of what I am missing?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

**EDIT**: UP!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that IIS doesn't accept '+' character in URLs, [as explained here](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/60/404-Error-in-IIS-7-when-using-a-Url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path), and that I was using `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` to generate my URLs.

The workaround I implemented was simply to replace '+' by '--'.